# Arranging squares by coordinates

Tags: java, arraylist, 2d, graphics2d

I do a project in Java. For the project I have to arrange squares(a class I created, I will give the code at the end) according to their coordinates(the left up corner of the window was chosen as 0,0). Right now the squares are in an ArrayList. I think it is important to say that not all of them are in the same size, but together they make a rectangle(or a square). I thought about arranging them in a 2d array. Do someone has an idea how to?

```
    public class Square3D extends Frame {

    public Point3D p1, p2, p3, p4;
    public Color color;
    public Square3D() {
        this.p1 = new Point3D(0, 0, 0, 1);
        this.p2 = new Point3D(0, 60, 0, 1);
        this.p3 = new Point3D(60, 60, 0, 1);
        this.p4 = new Point3D(60, 0, 0, 1);
        this.color = Color.blue;
    }
}
```

You can assume that all the "squares" are rectangles or squares(in each one the proportion between the X and the Y is the same).

Comment: Try using the `Rectangle` class. It does just this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a kd-tree or a rectangle tree. When you have only squares you can also try a quadtree. If you want to pack the tree you can use the treemap algorithm and put the rectangle  where it fits and split the tree along the 2-axis. Here is an example: http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/.

Comment: I am using a quadtree to create them recursively, but they are not organized by location.

Comment: @TJR: What do you mean by location? Do you mean a bin-packing? Read my answer, I have an update.

Comment: Actually, my problem is really close to that and it might help. There are to problems - first, I don't know whether the first rectangles in the ArrayList are the biggest.Second - their arranging need to be according to their X and Y coordinates(because of the color). In addition, the code there is not in Java, so I don't really understand it...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a way to draw a list of squares? Like so...

```
for (Square3D square : square3DArrayList)
{
  //TODO draw square at square.p1, square.p2, square.p3, square.p4
}
```

Comment: No, I don't need to draw them, I have a draw function. I just need to arrange(or organize) them, I think that 2d array is the best way, according to their location in the window.